# iTextSharp error The document has no pages. When using XMLWorkerHelper

Tags: c#, itext, html-to-pdf

I am trying to create PDF document from html. When I use HTMLWorker of iTextSharp, it produces pdf file with formatting issues. So I created the V2 version as follows using XMLWorkerHelper instade of HTMLWorker to enhance results.

```
    public void GeneratePdfFromHtml_V2(string html, string outputPath)
    {
        try
        {
            string strHtml = string.Empty;
            strHtml = html;
            strHtml = strHtml.Replace("\r\n", "");
            strHtml = strHtml.Replace("\0", "");

            using (Stream fs = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4))
                {
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
                    doc.Open();
                    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(strHtml))
                    {
                        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, sr);
                    }
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

But when I call the above function `GeneratePdfFromHtml_V2("<h1>hello world</h1>", "c:/test_doc.pdf");` I get the following error at this `XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, sr);` line.

**The document has no pages.**

```
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPages.WritePageTree()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close()
   at iTextSharp.text.Document.Close()
   at PdfGenerator.GeneratePdfFromHtml_V2(String html, String outputPath) in D:\PdfGenerator.cs:line 123
```

can any one test the code and figure out the problem with it?
I am using iTextSharp 5.5.13.3 and
dotNet core 2.1